# Detect compilation on Bada OS

Tags: preprocessor, operating-system, simulator, conditional-compilation, bada

I would like to do something similar to `#ifdef __linux__`, but with the bada SDK. Is there a constant defined by default?
Also, can I detect when I am compiling for the simulator?

Comment: For now I guess I am going to settle with "-D TARGET_OS_BADA"

Answer (score 1):

You can, by checking the MingW Compiler's keyword, here's an interesting [link](http://predef.sourceforge.net/precomp.html) that would point you in the right spot... so in theory you could have it this way

```
#ifdef __MINGW32__
 /* we're in the simulator target */
#else
 /* we're in the native target */
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I use something like :

```
#ifdef SHP
# define CONFIG_SUPPORT_API_Osp 1 // bada
#endif
```

I wish there is also a define that tell sdk version or target api too ..

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    // Your code
#endif
```